# A Small programming puzzle

Tags: python

```
z=[1,2,","]

count=0


for i in z:
    if (",") in z:
        count+=1
        print count
```

this python code counts all commas in list `z`.Why? Answer is 3.when it should be one. One can test by changing elements.

If list element comma "," is deleted, program  produces blank, not 2 commas as count.

Questions:

1. can someone answer please why comma gets counted only?
2. why comma count is 3 when it should be one.

thanks

Comment: While your specific concern in addressed in numerous answers, also consider whether your approach is the most efficient/readable.  See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists count() as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

change it to

```
if (",") in i:
```

really you should use better names (`i` *typically* refers to an index into an array or a integer count.. whereas you are iterating over the actual items in the list)

```
for item in z:
    if (",") in item:
        count+=1
        print count
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing 3 as your answer is because of this:

```
if (",") in z:
```

You are iterating across the list and for each element in the list you are checking if `','` is in the list `z`, which it is. You count variable is incremented accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Three times you checked whether ',' is in z.  Yes it is.  Yes it still is.  Yes again.  That's 3.

```
for i in z:
    if i == ',':
        count+=1
print count
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `if (",") in z` python checks if the comma is in your list and it will return true each time and when you delete the "," from the list it never produce true and the count would be zero so the correct version would be

```
z=[1,2,","]  

count=0

for i in z:
    if i == ',':
        count+=1
print count
```

and also your print statement should not be in your for body